# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Interfaces.IUser] to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable[Interfaces.IUser]

Tags: c#, automapper

I don't know what is a problem I'm using the Repository pattern in API request here is the code

In Repository

```
public IQueryable<IUser> Get()
{
        return _mapper.Map<IQueryable<IUser>>(_context.Users.AsQueryable());
}
```

In API

```
// GET: api/UserEntities
public IQueryable<UserEntity> GetUsers()
{
        return _mapper.Map<IQueryable<UserEntity>>(_repository.Get());
}
```

Comment: what's the type of _context.Users ?

Comment: Oh I put _context.Users.AsQueryable()

Comment: @viveknuna I tried ToList, but I get same response

Comment: Where did you put `.ToList()`?

Comment: Insted of AsQueryable()

Comment: Well, it seems likely that your method (that contains the line of code you've shown) has a return type of `List<IUser>`, but you're mapping the response as an `IQueryable<IUser>`. I think Vivek's suggestion was to call `.ToList()` on the mapped result.

Comment: Method is IQueryable type

Comment: This code is simply terrible. Properly execute the database call with `await context.Users.ToArrayAsync();` and then map the results. Don't map `IQueryable<T>` which can have completely unintended side-effects. Also, don't use `AsEnumerable` which returns the entire table in a synchronous, blocking manner.

Comment: It's just a test so I don't have so much data, and I want to return just more than 1 user, I don't really need to implement a service layer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the basics. This piece of code:

```
public IQueryable<IUser> Get()
{
    return _mapper.Map<IQueryable<IUser>>(_context.Users.AsQueryable());
}
```

is completely wrong in **multiple** ways:

- You should not return `IQueryable<T>`. That leaks the Entity Framework dependency.
- You should not run a mapper against an `IQueryable<T>`, but rather against elements of the result.
- Doing `AsQueryable()` on an `IQueryable<T>` is the same as doing `"string".ToString()` -> no effect, at all.
- Changing `AsQueryable()` for `AsEnumerable()` would return the entire table synchronously.

Even if this is just for learning purposes, this is entirely incorrect, and you're just learning terribly wrong practices. It's best to learn how to do things **correctly** from the beginning.

Since you are using Entity Framework, and clearly leaking the dependency isn't an issue, let's get rid of that entire method and do it correctly:

```
// GET: api/UserEntities
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserEntity>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    var users = await _context.Users
        .Select(x => _mapper.Map<UserEntity>(x))
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToArrayAsync();

    return users;
}
```

Entity Framework implements Unit of Work and Repository patterns, so putting it behind another Repository is a waste of time that only adds complexity with no added benefit except in the rare cases where removing EF is a real option.

Comment: I'm learning and using Repository patterns cause  I'll get maximum points for architecture, also If I have to change from EF to something else it will be much easier. But thanks for your response, help, and will to teach me something. Have a nice day

Answer (score -2):

Here is how I simply fixed it,
In Repository

```
public IQueryable<IUser> Get()
{
    return _mapper.Map<List<IUser>>(_context.Users).AsQueryable();
}
```

In API

```
public IQueryable<UserEntity> GetUsers()
{
    return _mapper.Map<List<UserEntity>>(_repository.Get()).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: This is **wrong**! An `IQueryable<T>` represents a **query against an external system not yet executed**, while what you have is an in-memory list of data already. As for the Controller, Controllers should never return `IQueryable<T>`, that can have a lot of unintended consequences like multiple executions of the same query.